# Strange behavior of loop

Tags: java, android

Ok I've spent hours on this now, so pls forgive me if the solution for this might be very simple. I have a loop which iterates over an image, it starts at a certain pixel, and from this point, it goes several pixels to the left and checks if they fulfill a condition. If I find a point which fulfills, I return it. If I do not find one or run out of the image, I return `{-1,-1}`

```
private static int[] checkLineLeft(int[] point, Mat intensity) {
    for (int i = 1; i < intensity.width()*0.2f; i += 1) {
        try {
            if (intensity.get(point[1], point[0] - i)[0] > 100
                    && intensity.get(point[1], point[0] - i)[2] < 50) {
                return new int[]{point[0] - i, point[1]};
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new int[]{-1, -1};
        }
    }
    return new int[]{-1, -1};
}
```

My Problem is that I get really strange results. I have always a point of `{-23646,286}` (second value is good). I cannot come up with an explanation why this can even happen. I debugged this and saw that the condition was not fulfilled at a certain point (the point that I want to detect), but the function just goes back to the beginning of the for-loop and starts all over instead of returning my `{-1,-1}`.

Here is how I call the function as well:

```
int[] newMarkerBottom = checkLineLeft(markerBottom, intensity);
while (newMarkerBottom[0] != -1) {
    markerBottom = newMarkerBottom.clone();
    newMarkerBottom = checkLineLeft(markerBottom, intensity);
}
```

**EDIT**

I checked again, and there is no exception that gets caught when the inner part of the `if` condition is false. Debugger just jumps back to the line `for(...)` and keeps going.

**EDIT 2**

I am running this on an Android Application. However, I think this cannot be part of the problem here.

**EDIT3**

This might help: When I set a breakpoint to `return return new int[]{point[0] - i, point[1]};`, it will stop there, then in the next step it will jump to the last `return new int[]{-1, -1};` and will never reach the breakpoint again.

Comment: That catch block is dangerous. If an exception is happening, you will never know. It is always a good idea to at least log the exception somehow.

Comment: The `else`/`continue` isn't necessary.

Comment: Is it the first or second call to `checkLineLeft` which gives the strange result?

Comment: @m0skit0 i ran it without the `try/catch`. same result

Comment: @AndyTurner the first is giving the strange value

Comment: Btw, you are scanning points as [x,y] but returning [y,x]

Comment: @Draco18s Good Observation! But this is indeed intended. ;)

Comment: @ZerO well, ok then!

Comment: *"I have always a point of `{-23646,286}`"*, well, looks like your `point[0]` is rather small and `i` is quite high, so `point[0] - i` in `return new int[]{point[0] - i, point[1]}` will be negative. Can you create a runnable example, so we can run your code locally?

Comment: Well, if the condition is false your code goes back to the loop since you told it to with the `continue`: It will go to the next `i` (i.e. checks even more to the left). In order to know where `-23646` is coming from we would need to know point[0] and width, but I suspect `width()*0.2` is `23646` numbers bigger than `point[0]` when the condition finally comes true..

Comment: Not answer, but some recommendations: don't use array of `int`s for coordinates - create or use special class, where you'll specify x and y. Remove else and continue block - it's absolutely useless. Remove try-catch - they do nothing.
To answer your question - I need information about intensity.width parameter.

Comment: Yes once it hits the return it will exit the method.

Comment: @eckes widt*0.2 is 180. and point[0] (where is start) is 250.

Comment: that seems unlikely, 250-180 is not negative. Please provide a complete executable program. Are you sure your function is not called multiple times by the outer while loop with different border values?

Comment: Additional recommendation: change sources to
`for (int i = point[0]; i > point[0] - intensity.width()*0.2 && i >= 0 ; i--)` and update return to `return new int[]{i, point[1]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of reasoning of strange behavior of your source (there are many possibilities).

According to your sources it looks like final sources should look like:
additional class:

```
public class Point {
   private final int x;
   private final int y;
   public Point(int x, int y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
   }
   public int getX() {
     return x;
   }
   public int getY() {
     return y;
   }
}
```

checker method:

```
private static Point checkLineLeft(Point point, Mat intensive) {
  int minX = point.getX() - intensive.width()*0.2;
  int y = point.getY();
  for (int x = point.getX() - 1 ; x > minX && x >= 0 ; x--) {
    if (isCorrectPoint(intensive, x, y)) {
      return new Point(x, y);
    }
  }
  return new Point(-1, -1);
}

private static boolean isCorrectPoint(Mat intensive, int x, int y) {
  return intensity.get(y, x)[0] > 100
      && intensity.get(y, x)[2] < 50;
}
```

PS some updates to make source match clearer and improve readability.

Comment: I adepted your code slightly and tried it. And it works! Thank you so much!

However, I am really curious to understand why my solution would not work =)